# Fail to detect and fail to prompt error for same data in the SQL server and textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to ensure that the user does not insert data that already exists in the database.

I have used datareader to read the data from the SQL server.

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("Select policeid, nric from PoliceAccount where policeid = @policeid", con);
        SqlDataReader dr;

        select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@policeid", tbpid.Text);

        dr = select.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            if (tbpid.Text.Equals(dr["policeid"].ToString()) && (tbnric.Text.Equals(dr["nric"].ToString())))
                {

                    lbmsg.Text = "This police account has already exist. Please verify the details again.";

                }
                else if (tbpid.Text.Equals(dr["policeid"].ToString()))
                {
                    lbmsg.Text = "This police ID has already exists. Please generate another";
                }
                else if (tbnric.Text.Equals(dr["nric"].ToString()))
                {
                    lbmsg.Text  ="This NRIC has already exist. Please ensure that the NRIC is correct";
                }

}

        else
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into PoliceAccount(policeid, password, nric, fullname, postedto)  values('" + tbpid.Text.Trim() + "','" + tbpid.Text.Trim() + "','" + tbnric.Text.Trim() + "','" + tbfullname.Text.Trim() + "', '" + ddllocation.SelectedValue + "')", conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            lbmsg.Text = "Congratulations. The police account of ID " + tbpid.Text + " has been successfully added. You may edit the profile via the edit profile tab above";

            tbpid.Text = "";
            tbnric.Text = "";
            tbfullname.Text = "";
            ddllocation.SelectedValue = "Select Location";


        }

        }
```

However, despite putting the same policeID in the textbox that already exists in the database, the error message "Police ID already exists" did not appear and the inserting of data failed.

However, when I type a different PoliceID but the same NRIC, the error msg did not appear but the insertion of the data succeeded.

I'm just curious to know why doesn't my error message appear despite the same policeID.

***UPDATE***

I have added

```
.Text
```

into my ID check and only one of the error message appears.

However, when i added `.Text` into NRIC, something weird happens. When i type the same ID but different NRIC, the primary key error appears on my VS2012 (obviously it happens because i added a primary key constraint on pid) which means it totally ignores my duplicate check. However, when i type the different ID but the same NRIC, the information was submitted into the database. which totally ignores the NRIC check that i have done.

I'm still curious to know why this happens.

***Please refer to this [thread for the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917752/skipped-one-error-checking-in-if-else-statement)***

Answer (score 2):

In the row

```
if (tbpid.Equals(dr["policeid"].ToString()))
```

you forgot `.Text`:

```
if (tbpid.Text.Equals(dr["policeid"].ToString()))
```

the same in checking for NRIC

And regarding

> However, when i type a different PoliceID but the same NRIC, the error msg did not appear but the insertion of the data succeeded.

I suppose your table hase uniq constraint on `policeid` column, but not on `nric`

Comment: I have updated something in my question. But as what you said, After adding `.Text` into tbpid, the error message works. But when i added `.Text` into NRIC, something weird happens. When i type the same ID but different NRIC, the primary key error appears on my VS2012 (obviously it happens because i added a primary key constraint on pid). However, when i type the different ID but the same NRIC, the information was submitted into the database. Totally ignoring the NRIC check that i have done.