# Skipped one error checking in if else statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have this error checking in my program using the if else statment. I got 2 things to check. They are

1. PoliceID(PK)
2. NRIC

The statement below checks if the textbox has the same value for PoliceID and NRIC  as in the database.

```
if (tbpid.Text.Equals(dr["policeid"].ToString().Trim()) && (tbnric.Text.Equals(dr["nric"].ToString().Trim())))
                {

                    lbmsg.Text = "This police account has already exist. Please verify the details again.";

                }
```

If the textbox (police id) has the same value as in the database, they will give another different error.

```
 if (tbpid.Text.Equals(dr["policeid"].ToString()))
                {
                    lbmsg.Text = "This police ID has already exists. Please generate another Police ID";
                }
```

If the textbox (NRIC) has the same value as in the database, they will give another error

```
if (tbnric.Text.Equals(dr["nric"].ToString()))
                {
                    lbmsg.Text  ="This NRIC has already exist. Please ensure that the NRIC is correct";
                }
```

and if i were to combine all error checking message together it will be like this.

```
 protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("Select policeid, nric from PoliceAccount where policeid = @policeid" , con);
            SqlDataReader dr;

            select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@policeid", tbpid.Text);            

            dr = select.ExecuteReader();
            if(dr.Read())
            {
                if (tbpid.Text.Equals(dr["policeid"].ToString().Trim()) && (tbnric.Text.Equals(dr["nric"].ToString().Trim())))
                {

                    lbmsg.Text = "This police account has already exist. Please verify the details again.";

                }
                else if (tbpid.Text.Equals(dr["policeid"].ToString()))
                {
                    lbmsg.Text = "This police ID has already exists. Please generate another Police ID";
                }
                else if (tbnric.Text.Equals(dr["nric"].ToString()))
                {
                    lbmsg.Text  ="This NRIC has already exist. Please ensure that the NRIC is correct";
                }

            }

            else
            {

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI");
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into PoliceAccount(policeid, password, nric, fullname, postedto)  values('" + tbpid.Text.Trim() + "','" + tbpid.Text.Trim() + "','" + tbnric.Text.Trim() + "','" + tbfullname.Text.Trim() + "', '" + ddllocation.SelectedValue + "')", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

                lbmsg.Text = "Congratulations. The police account of ID " + tbpid.Text + " has been successfully added. You may edit the profile via the edit profile tab above";

                tbpid.Text = "";
                tbnric.Text = "";
                tbfullname.Text = "";
                ddllocation.SelectedValue = "Select Location";


            }

            //ConfirmButtonExtender2.ConfirmText = "Are you sure you want to add this Police Account " + tbpid.Text + " ?";
        }

    }
```

However the problem here is, the first two statement of the error checking message managed to work. Unfortunately, the NRIC one did not work. For example, if i were to type a different policeID but the same NRIC, the data is still being inserted into the database which means it totally ignore the NRIC error check above. I have been looking at it for hours and i have yet to find the problem. Would appreciate if anyone can guide me on this.

To add on, in my database, i have set my **primary key** as the **policeID** while **NRIC** is just a **regular data column** in my database

Regards.

Comment: You are making me sad. Your code is so vulnerable for sql injection, you should consider fixing it.

Comment: I'm aware of something called sql injection but my main concern isn't about that at the moment. I'm still trying to do a simple application which will only be used by me. As for the security aspects, i will definitely look into after completing my project. Thank you for your concern though.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan read the answer below i m sure it will help u?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Last one didn't work because of this query

`Select policeid, nric from PoliceAccount where policeid=@policeid` 
This will not return any row since ploiceid doesn't exist means `dr.Read()` is false since no rows to read , so it goes directly in else part where you are inserting data in database . So to make it work. try like this...

```
 if(dr.Read())
            {
                if (tbpid.Text.Equals(dr["policeid"].ToString().Trim()) && (tbnric.Text.Equals(dr["nric"].ToString().Trim())))
                {

                    lbmsg.Text = "This police account has already exist. Please verify the details again.";

                }
                else if (tbpid.Text.Equals(dr["policeid"].ToString()))
                {
                    lbmsg.Text = "This police ID has already exists. Please generate another Police ID";
                }
            }

            else
            {
 if (tbnric.Text.Equals(dr["nric"].ToString()))
                {
                    lbmsg.Text  ="This NRIC has already exist. Please ensure that the NRIC is correct";
                }
else
{

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI");
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into PoliceAccount(policeid, password, nric, fullname, postedto)  values('" + tbpid.Text.Trim() + "','" + tbpid.Text.Trim() + "','" + tbnric.Text.Trim() + "','" + tbfullname.Text.Trim() + "', '" + ddllocation.SelectedValue + "')", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

                lbmsg.Text = "Congratulations. The police account of ID " + tbpid.Text + " has been successfully added. You may edit the profile via the edit profile tab above";

                tbpid.Text = "";
                tbnric.Text = "";
                tbfullname.Text = "";
                ddllocation.SelectedValue = "Select Location";
}
}
```

To make your Existing code work try this query

`Select policeid, nric from PoliceAccount where policeid=@policeid or nric=@nric`

It will always return rows if one of the id exist in database if both didn't than it insert in to database.

Comment: Actually everything is fine. The SQL statement you gave below is right. Initially i put `where policeid=@policeid and nric=@nric` after changing the `and` to `or` it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your select statement seems to be the problem. It seems like you want nric to be unique too yet you don't use it in the where clause of your select statement. The way you have it now, as long as policeid is unique, any nric value will be fine. In other words, if first two checks pass, then the third one will too. Try this instead:

```
SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("Select policeid, nric from PoliceAccount where policeid = @policeid or nric = @nric" , con);
SqlDataReader dr;

select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@policeid", tbpid.Text);
select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nric", tbnric.Text);

dr = select.ExecuteReader();
```

However if you don't want nric to be unique, then your code works fine!